# What is the mental illness of Tiffany in Silver Linings Playbook?

Tags: character, silver-linings-playbook

Tiffany in *Silver Linings Playbook* said she was depressed. So, I guess she had at least one depressive episode. Does she have MDD, BD (like Pat), BPD or PTSD? I read some speculation on Tiffany having at least one of those, but I don't think she was diagnosed. Was she? Is there any official word on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official word (from the book blurb) is that she's suffering from [clinical depression](http://matthewquickwriter.com/novels/the-silver-linings-playbook/).

> When Pat meets the tragically widowed, physically fit, and clinically
>   depressed Tiffany, she offers to act as a liaison between him and his
>   wife, if only he will give up watching football, agree to perform in
>   this year’s Dance Away Depression competition, and promise not to tell
>   anyone about their ‘contract.’ All the while, Pat keeps searching for
>   his silver lining.

As far as her '*undiagnosed*' conditions are concerned, the author has suggested (in [this interview](http://www.eastvalleytribune.com/get_out/movies/article_c6da13fe-359c-11e2-9437-0019bb2963f4.html)) that she may also be suffering from anxiety issues:

> **Could you tell me about the creation of Tiffany? Was the character inspired by anybody you know?**
>
> *It’s funny; people ask me that all the time, like, “Did you know someone who needed to sleep with everybody in the office?” and the
>   boring answer is “no.” I think what Tiffany really represents is that
>   explosive quality that forces you to take a hard look at yourself. Pat
>   is delusional – especially in the book, he’s much more delusional in
>   the book. He just does not want to face reality and Tiffany is the one
>   that grabs Pat’s head and makes him look squarely in the mirror at
>   someone that he doesn’t want to see.*
>
> ...
>
> *Growing up in a blue-collar neighborhood, you didn’t talk about stuff like that. To use the word “depression,” that was not something I was
>   comfortable with for most of my life and I think my wife really forced
>   me to look at the fact that I was not happy, I was depressed, I had
>   anxiety issues and I wasn’t really living the life that I wanted to
>   live. That was a hard thing for me to admit in my 20’s. I think,
>   metaphorically, that experience probably inspired, on a subconscious
>   level, Tiffany.*